# How to read substitution char with ifstream in C++ ? (SUB in ASCII)

Tags: c++, ascii, ifstream, getline, substitution

I am having a hard time finding out why I can't read all characters with fstream get function.
My code is the following :

```
ifstream input_stream(input_filename.c_str(), ios::in);
string input;

if(input_stream)
{
    char character;
    while(input_stream.get(character))
    {
        input += character;
    }
    input_stream.close();
}
else
    cerr << "Error" << endl;
```

By testing a little, I found out that I get a problem when character = 26 (SUB in ASCII) because input_stream.get(26) return false and I get out of my while loop.
I would like to put in my string input all characters from the file including SUB.
I tryed with getline function at first and I got a similar problem.
Could you help me please ?

Comment: On which operating system?

Comment: Got to be Windows - dear old control-z strikes again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to read a binary stream, not a textual one (since *SUB* i.e. `'0x1a'` (that is 26) is a control character in ASCII or UTF8, not a printable one) Use [ios::binary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) at opening time:

```
 ifstream input_stream(input_filename.c_str(), ios::in | ios::binary);
```

Maybe you would then code

```
 do {
   int c= input_stream.get();
   if (c==std::char_traits::eof()) break;
   input += (char)c;
 } while (!input_stream.fail());
```

Did you consider using [std::getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read an entire line, assuming the input file is still organized in (`'\n'` terminated) lines?